# Show the sum of product attributes JS wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a product bundle box where a visitor can select three products and gets added to the bundle, it shows as follows 
[image]

I've tried this but it wouldn't show the attributes it only shows the price

```
$dynamicPrice = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_per_product_pricing_active', true);
$dynamicFett = get_post_meta(  'attribute_fett' );
$dynamicKolhydrater = get_post_meta(  'attribute_kolhydrater' );
$dynamicProtein = get_post_meta(  'attribute_protein' );
$dynamicKcal = get_post_meta(  'attribute_kcal' );

<div class="cpb-row cpb-clear cpb-quantity-box--assets cpb-align-items-center cpb-justify-content-center">

            <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price-label'><?php echo $giftBoxTotal; ?></div>
            <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price wdm-bundle-total wdm_bundle_price' data-dynamic-price = "<?php echo $dynamicPrice ?>" data-total-bundle-price = "0"><div class='cpb-col-xl-7 cpb-col-lg-7 cpb-col-md-7 cpb-col-sm-7'><?php do_action("wdm_product_price_html"); ?></div></div>
             <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price-label'>Totalt Protein</div>
            <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price wdm-bundle-total wdm_bundle_price' data-dynamic-price = "<?php echo $dynamicProtein; >" data-total-bundle-price = "0"><div class='cpb-col-xl-7 cpb-col-lg-7 cpb-col-md-7 cpb-col-sm-7'><?php echo $dynamicProtein; ?></div></div>
             <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price-label'>Totalt Fett</div>
            <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price wdm-bundle-total wdm_bundle_price' data-dynamic-price = "<?php echo $dynamicFett ?>" data-total-bundle-price = "0"><div class='cpb-col-xl-7 cpb-col-lg-7 cpb-col-md-7 cpb-col-sm-7'><?php echo $dynamicFett; ?></div></div>
             <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price-label'>Totalt Kolhydrater</div>
            <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price wdm-bundle-total wdm_bundle_price' data-dynamic-price = "<?php echo $dynamicKolhydrater ?>" data-total-bundle-price = "0"><div class='cpb-col-xl-7 cpb-col-lg-7 cpb-col-md-7 cpb-col-sm-7'><?php echo $dynamicKolhydrater; ?></div></div>
             <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price-label'>Totalt Kcal</div>
            <div class='cpb-col-xl-6 cpb-col-lg-6 cpb-col-md-6 cpb-col-sm-6 bundle-product--price wdm-bundle-total wdm_bundle_price' data-dynamic-price = "<?php echo $dynamicKcal ?>" data-total-bundle-price = "0"><div class='cpb-col-xl-7 cpb-col-lg-7 cpb-col-md-7 cpb-col-sm-7'><?php echo $dynamicKcal; ?></div></div>
        </div>
```

what I'm trying to do is sum the product attributes that are already being show for each products using this code

```
   <?php
    }

    $text = str_replace('_', '', $bundled_item_id);
    $full_attributes_right = '';
    if(isset(get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_kcal' )[0])){
        $full_attributes_right .= 'kcal: ' . get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_kcal' )[0] . '<br />';
    }


    $full_attributes_left = '';
    if(isset(get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_protein' )[0])){
        $full_attributes_left .= 'Protein: ' . get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_protein' )[0] . '<br />';
    }
    if(isset(get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_kolhydrater' )[0])){
        $full_attributes_left .= 'Kolhydrater: ' . get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_kolhydrater' )[0] . '<br />';
    }
    if(isset(get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_fett' )[0])){
        $full_attributes_left .= 'Fett: ' . get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_fett' )[0] . '<br />';
    }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**

While trying to solve this, I found that this line of JS code is what is displaying the attribute below the product name..

```
    var stock_in_out = $this.find( ".wdm_stock" ).html();
    var counter = 0;
    if ( stock_in_out != "Out of stock" && canProductBeAdded(item_id) && !$this.hasClass('wdm-no-stock')) {
        //If sold individual set flag for first time
        //console.log($this.find( ".variations select option:selected" ).attr('price'));
        var product = {
            product_id: $this.find( ".variations select option:selected" ).attr('product_id'),
            title: $this.find( ".product-title a" ).text().trim(),
            weight: $this.find( ".variations select option:selected" ).text(),
            price: $this.find( ".variations select option:selected" ).attr('price'),
            left_text: $this.find( ".variations select option:selected" ).attr('data_description').split("|")[0],
            right_text: $this.find( ".variations select option:selected" ).attr('data_description').split("|")[1]
        }
        console.log(product);
        addProductInfo(product); 

        if (isi) {
            sld_ind[item_id] = 1;
        }
```

How can I make it show the sum?

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Can you please `var_dump` the following variables : `$dynamicFett` , `$dynamicKolhydrater` , `$dynamicProtein` , `$dynamicKcal` and post the outcome in the question.

Comment: Dump them after declaration, like shown here : https://gist.github.com/saibbyweb/8d38457720a4130f405e737af0effa4c

Comment: @saibbyweb I got string(3) "yes" bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)

Comment: @saibbyweb I updated the post with the JS code displaying the attribute below the product name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code, try replacing

```
$dynamicFett = get_post_meta(  'attribute_fett' );
$dynamicKolhydrater = get_post_meta(  'attribute_kolhydrater' );
$dynamicProtein = get_post_meta(  'attribute_protein' );
$dynamicKcal = get_post_meta(  'attribute_kcal' );
```

with

```
$dynamicFett = get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'attribute_fett', true );
$dynamicKolhydrater = get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'attribute_kolhydrater', true );
$dynamicProtein = get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'attribute_protein', true );
$dynamicKcal = get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'attribute_kcal', true );
```

Comment: that's what I've received string(3) "yes" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(3) "yes"

Comment: you can see the whole code with related files here https://gist.github.com/arnanzo/dc61fe8b01f68cea0d53ff842f7fbbff

Comment: I can upload and give you access if you wish

Comment: Okay, upload it somewhere and provide me the access. Skype/Email?

Comment: sorry was away.. skype is live:e5703b292d2f68f

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping your get_post_meta call in parentheses before indexing the returned array:

(get_post_meta( $text, 'attribute_kcal' ))[0]

Otherwise, pull your code apart and confirm that get_post_meta is returning a value.
Also check that $text is actually just a post id.